# How do I keep raw HTML in my RSS feed and not lose my paragraph breaks?

Tags: posts, tags, rss

My blog posts have paragraph breaks, but my RSS feed does not.

Here's a screenshot of the Code Editor for a post that shows paragraph breaks.

[image: Paragraph breaks shown]

And the rss feed which doesn't seem to have them: https://lighthousebiblestudies.com/feed/

Why is the formatting being stripped? Please look at the post title "Lists - Establish Boundaries around the Health of Your Soul."

Comment: All the posts I see in the RSS feed have paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look. However, please note the formatting for "Lists - Establish Boundaries around the Health of Your Soul." No paragraph breaks as seen here:

/></a><p>Establish boundaries around the health of your soul. Establish mental and emotional boundaries to guard your heart from injury and from being unnecessarily crushed.Establish boundaries that stop mean or thoughtless words or actions from having an undue influence.

 ... And so on. Not enough room here for the whole post.